# Custom Proxy in Create React App using Typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I need to proxy requests from a Create React App to a separate API server, and set that server dynamically or with environment variables. I followed [configuring proxy manually](https://facebook.github.io/create-react-app/docs/proxying-api-requests-in-development#configuring-the-proxy-manually), however I am using TypeScript. `react-scripts-ts` does not seem to load `src/setupProxy.js` even after updating to latest version (v3.1.0). I got it working with vanilla javascript, but am unable to get it to work with TypeScript. Has anyone gotten setupProxy to work with React TypeScript?

Comment: Regular CRA [supports TS now](https://facebook.github.io/create-react-app/docs/adding-typescript) if it's an option for you to upgrade.

Comment: [Upgrading from react-scripts-ts to Create React App v2.1](https://joshblog.net/2018/upgrading-a-react-and-typescript-app-from-react-scripts-ts-to-create-react-app-v2-1/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After code diving, it appears the [typescript create-react-app](https://github.com/wmonk/create-react-app) has not yet incorporated custom proxy functionality. I had to update two files:

https://github.com/samuelstevens9/create-react-app/blob/next/packages/react-scripts/config/paths.js

Added `proxySetup: resolveApp('src/setupProxy.js'),` to each module.exports, the last (3rd) being `proxySetup: resolveOwn('template/src/setupProxy.js'),`

https://github.com/samuelstevens9/create-react-app/blob/next/packages/react-scripts/config/webpackDevServer.config.js

Added `const fs = require('fs');` below line 15 `const paths = require('./paths');` and added

```
if (fs.existsSync(paths.proxySetup)) {
    // This registers user provided middleware for proxy reasons
    require(paths.proxySetup)(app);
}
```

inside the `before(app) { ... }` function towards the end of the file.

I am working on creating a pull request to the main repo, but it looks like the v3.1.0 files are different from the most up to date ones on the `next` branch. For now I use a patch script I made since we are using a lerna monorepo that updates all necessary packages:

```sh
#!/bin/bash
CONFIG_PATHS_URL="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/samuelstevens9/create-react-app/next/packages/react-scripts/config/paths.js"
CONFIG_WEBPACKDEVSERVER_URL="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/samuelstevens9/create-react-app/next/packages/react-scripts/config/webpackDevServer.config.js"
SETUPPROXY_URL="https://gist.githubusercontent.com/samuelstevens9/5872e72ac915dfc1a8ae2fdcef323899/raw/7f2c76d42bc0915026379dfc7884cb1bd97f56bb/setupProxy.js"

for f in packages/*; do
    if [ -d ${f} ]; then
        echo $f
        # Will not run if no directories are available
        NODE_MODULES_CONFIG_DIR=$f/node_modules/react-scripts-ts/config
        if [ -d "$NODE_MODULES_CONFIG_DIR" ]; then
          # Control will enter here if $DIRECTORY exists.
          echo $NODE_MODULES_CONFIG_DIR
          curl -o $NODE_MODULES_CONFIG_DIR/paths.js $CONFIG_PATHS_URL
          curl -o $NODE_MODULES_CONFIG_DIR/webpackDevServer.config.js $CONFIG_WEBPACKDEVSERVER_URL
          curl -o $f/src/setupProxy.js $SETUPPROXY_URL
        fi
    fi
done
```

And updates the `setupProxy.js` file in each package as well. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Now CRA supports Typescript but I couldn't make `setupProxy.js` to work.

My mistake was super dumb. `setupProxy` was outside `src/` folder.
So, make sure that you create `setupProxy` inside the folder `src`

`src/setupProxy.js`

My code looks like this:

```
module.exports = function (app) {
  app.use(
    '/api',
    createProxyMiddleware({
      target: process.env.REACT_APP_API_URI,
      changeOrigin: true,
    })
  )
}
```

Also, make sure that your `env` configuration is working. 
You need to install the package `env-cmd` and replace

`"start": "react-scripts start",`

for

`"start": "env-cmd -f .env.development.local react-scripts start",`